# How to pass variable to react-map-js callback

Tags: reactjs, react-map-gl

I need to make some draggable markers like:

```
const MyMarkers = () =>
            asset.map((item, index) => (
                <Marker
                    key={`marker-${index}`}
                    longitude={item.lng}
                    latitude={item.lat}
                    anchor="bottom"
                    onClick={e => {
                        console.log(item);
                    }}
                    draggable
                    onDragEnd={onMarkerDragEnd}
                >
                    <Pin />
                </Marker>
            ));
```

The problem is, I can't pass a id/value to each marker onMarkerDragEnd function, its parameters are fixed from Docs.

```
onDragEnd: (evt: MarkerDragEvent) => void
```

If I do

```
onDragEnd={onMarkerDragEnd(my_value)}
```

the function won't work.

I also tried data variable like:

```
<Marker
 ...
 data-id={item.assetId}
 data-value={item.name}
>
```

This won't work. I can't find the variable using:

```
 const onMarkerDragEnd = useCallback((event: MarkerDragEvent) => {
        var a = event.target.dataset; //dataset is undefined
    }, []);
```

Any suggestions?